# stories for publishing / stories to publish

Tags: sentence-choice

> I had a few **stories for publishing**.
>
> I had a few **stories to publish**.

As I understand the second version is most common [[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=stories%20for%20publishing%2Cstories%20to%20publish&year_start=1880&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cstories%20for%20publishing%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstories%20to%20publish%3B%2Cc0)] but I can't understand why. Could you explain it, please? Is there the difference in the meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second sentence is idiomatic, and clearly means, "stories that I intended to publish" or "... stories that were ready to publish".

The first sentence has quite an odd meaning, like, "I have a few stories for publishing, and the rest of my stories are for my personal enjoyment only."

It's worth noting that the first several citations from ngrams are uses like:

> I started to polish the stories for publishing
> explore and refine your stories for publishing
> [he] was in fact collecting stories for publishing in a written collection

In other words, all those "hits" for "stories for publishing" mean "*DO X **for the purpose of** publishing".

When you do an ngram search for "***have** stories for publishing*" or "***are** stories for publishing*", there are no hits at all.